# How to have React evaluate a dynamic variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have the following:

```
    {this.props.fields.map(field => (
      <div key={field.skill_id}>
        <Field
          component={RadioGroup}
          name={ 'skill_id_' + field.skill_id }
          title={field.name}
          activeValue={this.props.formState && this.props.formState.skill_id_${field.skill_id}}
          required={true}
          options={[
            { title: '1', value: '1' },
            { title: '2', value: '2' },
            { title: '3', value: '3' },
            { title: '4', value: '4' },
            { title: '5', value: '5' }
        ]} />

      </div>
    ))}
```

`activeValue` is not being evaluated correctly. I need this variable to be dynamically evaluated:

```
this.props.formState.skill_id_${field.skill_id}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I get

> syntax error: Unexpected token, expected } (57:82) 55
>   name={ 'skill_id_' + field.skill_id } 56
>   title={field.name} > 57
>   activeValue={this.props.formState && this.props.formState.skill_id_${field.skill_id}}

Comment: Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected } (57:82)

  55 |               name={ 'skill_id_' + field.skill_id }
  56 |               title={field.name}
> 57 |               activeValue={this.props.formState && this.props.formState.skill_id_${field.skill_id}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a dynamic key to the get the value from object so use `[]` notation.

Write it like this:

```
activeValue={this.props.formState && 
  this.props.formState[`skill_id_${field.skill_id}`]}
```

Check this Snippet:

```js
let obj = {
   a1: 1,
   a2: 2,
   a3: 3
};

[1,2,3].forEach(i => {

   console.log(`a${i} = `, obj[`a${i}`]);
   
})
```

Check the MDN doc for more details about **[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**.

Check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) for more details about bracket notation.

Comment: That is awesome. thank you! Will accept when stackoverflow lets me

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** to create a dynamic key and since it dynamic key, you should use the brackets notation for accesing an object property

```
this.props.formState[`skill_id_${field.skill_id}`]
```

Code:

```
{this.props.fields.map(field => (
  <div key={field.skill_id}>
    <Field
      component={RadioGroup}
      name={ 'skill_id_' + field.skill_id }
      title={field.name}
      activeValue={this.props.formState && this.props.formState[`skill_id_${field.skill_id}`]}
      required={true}
      options={[
        { title: '1', value: '1' },
        { title: '2', value: '2' },
        { title: '3', value: '3' },
        { title: '4', value: '4' },
        { title: '5', value: '5' }
    ]} />

  </div>
))}
```